# missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) dev/mapper does not exist

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, lvm

I had encountered an issue. I manually installed an older kernel version (linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic) using apt install linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic. Installation was successful, execute update-grub and update-initramfs -u -k all without any error.

When I reboot, i got the error as shown.:

[image: Error message 1]

Error from grub boot

[image: Error message 2]

Have anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Hi all, I have no issue on dell or huawei servers. The issue only occurred in HPE proliant gen10 server

Comment: You killed your system with these actions.  If you cannot get to a root shell prompt to reverse the changes, you will need to reinstall the OS.